# Visual Studio Code: Environment Variables not recognized when running Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, visual-studio-code

I am trying to recreate an Eclipse Run Configuration for Maven.

I have added the environment variables in launch.json:

```
"env": {"environment":"test", "applicationname":"asset-misc-api", "log_level":"debug","spicode":"SIKS","userid":"BB3820"}
```

The app recognizes the variables when I run it via the Spring Boot dashboard.

But when I instead run the app using a custom Maven goal, the environment variables are no longer passed to the app.

How can I ensure that the Visual Studio Code configuration is equivalent to my Eclipse Run Configuration as depicted in the images linked?

Maven goal:
[image: Maven goal]

Environment variables:
[image: Environment variables]

Comment: This is really frustrating. I've added env via launch.json and even maven.terminal.customEnv via settings.json and nothing seems to get read.

Comment: I have the same problem too. How to configure the environment variables in visual code as it is done in Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite)

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?